# Is it possible to set/change mlflow run name after run initial creation?

Tags: mlflow

I could not find a way yet of setting the runs name after the first start_run for that run (we can pass a name there).

I Know we can use tags but that is not the same thing. I would like to add a run relevant name, but very often we know the name only after run evaluation or while we're running the run interactively in notebook for example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible to edit run names from the MLflow UI. First, click into the run whose name you'd like to edit.

Then, edit the run name by clicking the dropdown next the run name (i.e. the downward-pointing caret in this image):

[image: Rename run dropdown]

There's currently no stable public API for setting run names - however, you can programmatically set/edit run names by setting the tag with key `mlflow.runName`, which is what the UI (currently) does under the hood.

Comment: as stated by the OP you can use `with mlflow.start_run(run_name='TEST')`while running code. mlflow.runName is reserved as system tag for internal use and can't be accessed externally after first run

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the latest version of mlflow as of now (1.26.0), the rename functionality UI has changed a bit to look like the below image where you can change the run name by using the 3 dots in the extreme right side. [image: mlflow rename a run]

Answer (score 3):

use the system tag directly:
`mlflow.set_tag("mlflow.runName", "run_name")`

https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/2804#issuecomment-640056129