# How can I set run_name in mlflow command line?

Tags: mlflow

MLFlow version: 1.4.0
Python version: 3.7.4

I'm running the UI as `mlflow server...` with all the required command line options.

I am logging to MLFlow as an MLFlow project, with the appropriate `MLproject.yaml` file. The project is being run on a Docker container, so the CMD looks like this:

`mlflow run . -P document_ids=${D2V_DOC_IDS} -P corpus_path=...  --no-conda --experiment-name=${EXPERIMENT_NAME}`

Running the experiment like this results in a blank run_name. I know there's a run_id but I'd also like to see the run_name and set it in my code -- either in the command line, or in my code as `mlflow.log....`.

I've looked at [Is it possible to set/change mlflow run name after run initial creation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57199472/is-it-possible-to-set-change-mlflow-run-name-after-run-initial-creation) but I want to programmatically set the run name instead of changing it manually on the UI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the parameters to `mlflow.start_run()` is `run_name`.  This would give you programmatic access to set the run name with each iteration. See the docs [here](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.html#mlflow.start_run).

Here's an example:

```py
from datetime import datetime

## Define the name of our run
name = "this run is gonna be bananas" + datetime.now()

## Start a new mlflow run and set the run name
with mlflow.start_run(run_name = name):

    ## ...train model, log metrics/params/model...

    ## End the run
    mlflow.end_run()
```

If you want to include set the name as part of an MLflow Project, you'll have to specify it as a parameter in the entry points to the project.  This is located in in the [MLproject file](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/projects.html#mlproject-file).  Then you can pass those values into the `mlflow.start_run()` function from the command line.

Comment: use the system tag directly:
`mlflow.set_tag("mlflow.runName", "run_name")`

https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/2804#issuecomment-640056129

Answer (score 0):

for CLI, this seems to now be available:

`--run-name <runname>`

https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/cli.html#cmdoption-mlflow-run-run-name