# Set run description programmatically in mlflow

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, mlflow

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57199472/is-it-possible-to-set-change-mlflow-run-name-after-run-initial-creation#:%7E:text=It%20is%20possible%20to%20edit,you%27d%20like%20to%20edit.&text=There%27s%20currently%20no%20stable%20public,the%20tag%20with%20key%20mlflow.), I'd like to edit/set the description of a run via code, instead of editing it via UI.

To clarify, I don't want to set the description of my entire experiment, only of a single run.

[image: Image showing what I want to edit]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways to set the description.

#### 1. `description` parameter

You can set a description using a markdown string for your run in `mlflow.start_run()` using `description` parameter. Here is an example.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # load dataset and other stuff

    run_description = """
### Header
This is a test **Bold**, *italic*, ~~strikethrough~~ text.
[And this is an example hayperlink](http://example.com/).
    """

    with mlflow.start_run(description=run_description) as run:
        # train model and other stuff
```

#### 2. `mlflow.note.content` tag

You can set/edit run names by setting the tag with the key `mlflow.note.content`, which is what the UI (currently) does under the hood.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # load dataset and other stuff

    run_description = """
### Header
This is a test **Bold**, *italic*, ~~strikethrough~~ text.
[And this is an example hayperlink](http://example.com/).
    """

    tags = {
        'mlflow.note.content': run_description
    }

    with mlflow.start_run(tags=tags) as run:
        # train model and other stuff
```

#### Result

[image: output of the given example]

---

If you set `description` parameter and `mlflow.note.content` tag in `mlflow.start_run()`, you'll get this error.

```
Description is already set via the tag mlflow.note.content in tags.
Remove the key mlflow.note.content from the tags or omit the description.
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer. Before I mark the question as done, is it possible to edit the description of an already active run?

Comment: Yes, you can edit the description of a run using the `mlflow.note.content` tag. @waykiki